error during boot process

I get this error during the boot process to Ubuntu, after showing this error my PC restarts and it either opens Ubuntu or it show this error:

After showing this it again restarts and then it opens up Ubuntu.
Ubuntu is not dual booted now, earlier it was with windows 10 but then window got some disk issues or something and I had to delete it completely.  Now i only have Ubuntu installed. It's been months since I had deleted windows and never faced any issues, now suddenly I don't know what happened to Ubuntu.
Does secure boot cause this issue because idk if it's disabled or enabled.

What happened with Windows may have been the start of a disk failure. It appears the disk may be failing even more. Time to replace the disk?

disk is not old, around or within 1.5 yr, since i bought it.Also, what happened with windows was also due to ubuntu and not disk. Before ubuntu my windows was working fine.

Ubuntu can not damage Windows and a disk can be bad the day you buy it.
